# jQuery Deferred / Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, promise, deferred

I'm trying to use deferred/promise in a loop, but I get strange behavior. My code is as follows:

```
var images = [];
var numImages = Blobs.length;
var image = {};
console.log("numImages: " + numImages);

function doAsyncOriginal(i) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    image.original = Blobs[i].key;
    image.resized = '';
    image.thumbnail = '';
    images.push(image);

    console.log("i: " + i + "  image: " + image.original);
    console.log("images[" + i + "]: " + images[i].original);

    defer.resolve(i);

    return defer.promise();
}

$(function(){
    var currentImage = doAsyncOriginal(0);

    for(var i = 1; i < numImages; i++){
        currentImage = currentImage.pipe(function(j) {
            return doAsyncOriginal(j+1);
        });
    }

    $.when(currentImage).done(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(images));
    });

});
```

The Blob used in the code is an array of objects that I get from remote webservice, which contains properties about the images (it comes from filepicker.io's pickandstore method to be precise).

When I run this, I get the following in console:

```
numImages: 2
i: 0  image: pictures_originals/3QnQVZd0RryCr8H2Q0Iq_picture1.jpg
images[0]: pictures_originals/3QnQVZd0RryCr8H2Q0Iq_picture1.jpg
i: 1  image: pictures_originals/MD3KO6GjT8SNFYoPcG8J_picture2.jpg
images[1]: pictures_originals/MD3KO6GjT8SNFYoPcG8J_picture2.jpg

[
    {
        "original":"pictures_originals/MD3KO6GjT8SNFYoPcG8J_picture2.jpg",
        "resized":"",
        "thumbnail":""
    },
    {
        "original":"pictures_originals/MD3KO6GjT8SNFYoPcG8J_picture2.jpg",
        "resized":"",
        "thumbnail":""
    }
]
```

Although it shows images[0] and images[1] correctly, when printing separately, the object array shows only twice images[1]!!!

Am I doing something wrong???

Thanks in advance for your time.

**UPDATE:** I corrected the code based on comment of @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: Side-note: You are wrapping code inside of `doAsyncOriginal` in a DOM ready handler. That is not needed as the calling code is already wrapped in one. That also means you are resolving the promises instantly.

Comment: Q: At what point are the images assumed to be loaded?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  thanks for comment, I removed them, but still works the same. Images are loaded already when run this code, Blob object returns from callback function. My problem is rather related with the loop. I want to pass the array to another function when all elements of the array are pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the same `image` object in every call to `doAsyncOriginal()`, so every element of your `images` array is pointing to the same object.

You need to create the object inside your function:

```
var image = {};  // <-- delete this

function doAsyncOriginal(i) {
    var image = {};

    // ...
}
```

This problem is unrelated to promises/deferreds, and promises/deferreds really aren't serving any purpose in your code. You could just do this:

```
$(function(){
    var images = Blobs.map(function (blob) {
        return { 
            original: blob.key,
            resized: '',
            thumbnail: ''
        };
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(images));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `doAsyncOriginal` you resolve your deferred before returning it's promise or even before adding the done handler on it.

You should delay the `defer.resolve(i)` call, so the deferred will be resolved later and enter the done handler...

```
function doAsyncOriginal(i) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    // ...

    // Function.bind equivalent to jQuery.proxy
    window.setTimeOut(defer.resolve.bind(defer, i), 0);

    return defer.promise();
}
```

Comment: The `.done()` handler on a promise is built in. It doesn't have to be manually added. What you are doing here is pointless.

Comment: @JLRishe I meant defining the callback function, thanks for correcting.

Comment: Callback functions don't have to be added to promises before they are resolved. The promises in OP's code work fine. The problem was unrelated to promises.

Comment: @JLRishe So on a **resolved** promise, if I define a done callback, the callback is called anyway ? How is this call managed (in stack, defered) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In Promises/A+ compliant promises, calls to the handlers must be deferred (https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34), but it looks like already-resolved jQuery promises call their handlers immediately: http://jsfiddle.net/acn4r4vs/